# How to select a row in listview only pressing a ImageView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView with a imageview in the left side. That I want to do is; if I press the imageView select the current row and if I press again, unselect the row. With my current code I can select a row with performLongClick() when I click the imageView but is not selected the current row. Seems that is random.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final HmViewHolder holder;
        row = convertView;


        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new HmViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.contact = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HmViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (multiMode) {
                    row.getTag();
                    row.setSelected(!row.isSelected());
                holder.contact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black);
                } else {
                    row.performLongClick();
                    holder.contact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact);
                }
            }
        });
    return row;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn´t want to use the onItemClickListener ? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Comment: @D.O. you can solve this using POJO class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> `ListView` it self `clikcable` and using a clickable inside an another
>   clickable is not good. So better don't set clicklistener on items
>   (ImageView and TextView) inside the listview because if you do like
>   that, it will confuse the environment and will not be able to
>   understand what exactly you want to click . So use onclick only on
>   listview.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Chris Banes's blogpost](https://chris.banes.me/2013/03/22/checkable-views/) about this topic.

Give it a read and I think all your troubles are solved. This is the bast way to create checkable lists, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Set your ImageView as clickable on your row layout xml like this.

```
<ImageView
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//ViewHolder Class

   class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv_details;
            RelativeLayout rl_expense_list;
            ImageView Iv_close;
        }

// `here is getView Method`
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{           final ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_list_row, parent, false);

                viewHolder.rl_expense_list = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(id.rl_expense_list);
                viewHolder.tv_details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tv_details);
                viewHolder.bt_close = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(id.iv_close);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.Iv_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ExpensesList.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Expense List");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Do You Want To Delete This Expense List?");
                    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            expensesDataModels.remove(position);
                            Customer_Feedback.expensesDataModels = expensesDataModels;
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
```